# Are mechanical pencils used on the ISS?

Tags: iss, identify-this-object

I have read through [this question ("Is it possible to use mechanical pencil instead of space pen in ISS?")](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/is-it-possible-to-use-mechanical-pencil-instead-of-space-pen-in-iss) and it seems that without specially made pencils, it's unlikely as there are better options.  (One answer mentions they were used at one time, but have been phased out).

However, at about `02:19` into the video [Demonstration of Acceleration Inside the International Space Station During a Reboost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=139&v=8MR3daaWLXI), it appears that there are many mechanical pencils on the left:

[image]

Are those mechanical pencils, or something else? That wall looks like writing utensils and they very much look like them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good eye!

Long-duration ISS crewmember [Clayton Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clayton_Anderson) writes [here](https://www.quora.com/What-pens-do-astronauts-use-in-space-today)  that mechanical pencils were provided on the ISS .  He also mentions Sharpies (also visible in your picture) and Fisher Space Pens.

Anderson was an ISS resident from June to November 2007. Your video appears to be from 2010.

Looks like the answers to that old question could use some work. One real-world picture can smack down a bunch of theories.

Comment: Thanks for that! Excellent source too! (...I had to reread that, as I first had hilarious images in my head of astronauts using ["Fisher Price Pens"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHaWe.jpg))