# Why did a shuttle astronaut have an open book during ascent?

Tags: space-shuttle, microgravity, ascent

In the top right of the [video of a shuttle launch](https://youtu.be/yaVVns_sTGY?t=1193) an astronaut has an open book resting on (attached to?) the left thigh.  What was the purpose of this book?  The astronaut then seems to take a pen or pencil with their right hand.  How was pen/pencil secured for when they entered freefall?  I'm assuming it was secured.

Comment: The astronaut in the left foreground also has one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Those are the Ascent Checklist and the Ascent/Entry Systems Procedures (AESP) book. These are used by the back-seater Mission Specialists (MSs) and contain copies of the cue cards and flip-books used by the front-seater commander and pilot.

The MSs follow along in the checklists and back up the front seaters.

The Ascent Checklist contains the nominal and ascent abort procedures. The AESP contains malfunction procedures. Both are available at the JSC flight data file page: https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/news/flightdatafiles/index.html

Comment: Is that a pen or pencil being used?  Is it secured somehow?

Comment: Yes, it's a pen or pencil being used to check off steps and write in numbers. They could be tethered but weren't always.

Comment: @Bob516 it should be a pen, not a pencil, as a pencil can release conductive graphite powder into the atmosphere at 0g, and possibly short out things

Comment: @RichieFrame both pens and pencils are used in space https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36178/6944

Comment: @uhoh the answers there are pretty much wrong.

Comment: @OrganicMarble okay then I've removed the link.